Does $\varprojlim X_s=*$ imply $\varprojlim\pi_*(X_s)= 0$
Let $X_0\xleftarrow{f_0}X_1\xleftarrow{f_1}X_2\xleftarrow{f_2}\cdots$ be a sequence of spectra such that $\varprojlim X_s=*$. Do we then already have $\varprojlim\pi_*(X_s)= 0$? I tried using the milnor $\lim^1$ sequence since homotopy groups of spectra don't commute with filtered limits. For context I am reading about the construction of the classical Adams spectral sequence and the question came up in the context of an Adam's resolution. So if that helps it should be fine to consider connective $X_s$ with finite type mod (p) cohomology.

Yes. This is an immediate consequence of the Milnor exact sequence
$$
    0 \to \varprojlim\nolimits_i^1 \pi_{* + 1}(X_i) \to \pi_*(\varprojlim\nolimits_i X_i) \to \varprojlim_\nolimits i \pi_*(X_i) \to 0
$$
If the middle term vanishes, then of course so must the terms at the left and right.
